# Not sure if I'm configuring my sessions correctly in Yii to do Single Sign On

Tags: php, yii, single-sign-on

I have a domain and I have two different Yii applications that use the same database. Both Applications have their own Login page but I wanted to make it so that if they log in from one application, they can have authorized access towards the other app and vice versa.

I previously asked a similar question as to what steps to take in order to execute this and now that I have an approach, I wanted to know if I'm configuring my main.php correctly. The last time I did this, the login button stopped working. I was following this guide: 
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/135/single-sign-on-across-multiple-subdomains/#hh1

Inside the main.php, I added this code:

```
'components' => array(
'user' => array(
    // enable cookie-based authentication
    'allowAutoLogin' => true,
),
// session configuration
'session' => array(
    'savePath' => '/sessCook', //I created this empty folder and placed it 
                              //outside of the protected folder. Currently the chmod is 775
    'cookieMode' => 'allow',
    'cookieParams' => array(
        'path' => '/sessCook', //I'm not sure if this is correct
        'domain' => 'http://www.mydomain.com/subdomain', //am I only supposed to place the          //parent domain?
        'httpOnly' => true,
    ),
),
```

Then after reading the guide, it said to add the following code inside the config file:

```
array(
'id' => 'http://www.mydomain.com/subdomainOfThisApplication',
```

Problem is, I'm not sure if they meant to place it inside the main.php ?

Finally, the instructions said to place this code and form the looks of the script, I placed it under my Components in WebUser.php:

```
class MyWebUser extends CWebUser
{
public $identityCookie = array(
    'path' => '/', //should the path be the /sessCook?
    'domain' => 'http://www.mydomain.com',
);
```

After saving everything, I ran the login page, inputted my username and password, and once I clicked submit, nothing happened. Am I inputting the right things?

Answer (score 1):

The `savePath` must be a path that exists on the server, and is accessible by both applications. Eg:

```
'savePath' => '/home/user/public_html/session_data'
```

Be sure to protect this, or place it outside the public_html. Also make sure this directory is writable for both applications.

The `path` you most likely want to change to `/`, the session cookie will be available on the whole domain.

```
'path' => '/',
```

The domain must be entered without `http://`. Start with a dot to make the session available on all domains:

```
'domain' => '.mydomain.com'
```

In the `MyCWebUser` class the settings must be the same as in your config file.

Comment: what about the array(
'id' => '.domain.com', ?

Where do i place this?

And for the savePath, do you think I did it correctly by just creating an empty directory where all the sessions go?

Comment: At the root level of the config file. See this topic: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/28945-yii-config-application-id/

Comment: You mentioned that the savePath should exists on the server. I have created a new folder outside the application. Example:

ebs->www->myYiiApp

I after creating the new folder, I placed it into ebs->www

How would I make the path towards there? Wouldn't it not work if I were to just place ebs/www/session_data  :)

Comment: Well after doing all of that, nothing really happens still. I don't know what I'm doing wrong!